# can i repost or carry POST data (if so, can i do it with redirects?)

Tags: asp.net, post, redirect, captcha

I want to redirect the user to another page to fill out a captcha but i would like to keep the post data, and if the captcha pass to send it 'back' and complete the previous page action.

When/if the user succeeds i like to add an captchaPass=true and would like access the post data and continue processing. Right now i am using redirects but ATM i am not required to use it.

**Is it possible to carry the post data**? keep in mind i may the user access multiple pages so separating data and not having a mixup is necessary.

One idea is to get and save all posted data *[1]* on the captcha page, and then recreate a middle white page with this form data and automatically make a new post to the previous page.

Can this work with out any issues with hash checks and security ?

Is there a better idea with out this white redirect page ?

*[1]* One other issue here, how to send this posted data with the redirect ? and not change the url - or make it too big to accept it. Keep in mine that a server transfer may not good idea because is complicate the thinks on captach post back.

### Update 1

The basic idea here is how some one capture the full post back of a page, show a different one page and then send the post back data to the original first one.

The reason is to stop a bad user, or an attacker bot program that try to bring down the pages/server by making many post back from different pages in short time. All that happens with out javascript, and most attackers use custom made programs that just make post of data to all page together try to bring down the system.

For example, if a page have a search box, is very easy for most of the the site to bring them down by start making hundred of random search with wildcard (called and Dos Attacks using SQL wildcards) and make the sql server and the computer spend his time and cpu to search and search thinks. So to prevent an attack like this you need to recognize multiple post backs from the same computer, and then the next step is to redirect him to a captcha page to block him out in case that is a computer program.

Other example, many page have email submit, very easy you can submit hundred times the email of his and full his mail box in no time with hundred of emails, or on a store to place all items on the cart again and again and full the database with stuff like that.

So ajax and javascript is not working in this case, and we need a way to redirect him after the post back to a page that can check if is a real user or an attacker and stop him - but if is a real user must return back to his normal action.

### Update 2

This all must be done in a general way, eg on BasePage, or on Global.asax or somewhere that is independed from the content of any page. Because we try to prevent a DoS attack, or multiple submit anywhere on any random place of any random page.

Yes I know how you can place a captcha on the contact page, but this is not what this question was first asked for - this questions asked how can carry post data to one different page, keep them there and then resend them back to the original one.

The obvious solution is to read all post back, and save them on the form, and then read them back and make on fly a form only with that data and make the post back. Here I am asking if there are any other better than this solution.

### Other Applications

There is also the case that a user is inside a page that request authentication, but the authentication ticket has expired, and the user make post back. In this case we need to keep somewhere all the posted back data, to proceed with the login page, and resend them back to the first page that request the authentication.

Comment: You probably want to send the captcha input instead of captchaPass=true and verify it on the server side.

Comment: @Josef, exactly, because then the client can set captchaPass=true itself and go :-)

Comment: Please explain the scenario like when you will redirect the user to fill captcha? I mean, I assume that you have 2 pages. PageA and PageB. Captcha is in PageB. in Which condition,  will you redirect the user to Page B to fill Captcha from PageA?

Comment: @Aristos: Your question is a bit different from my original one. I understand the problem now. I have two questions. 1) Are you trying to NOT STORE the post data serverside bc these are attacks? 2) If you not than why don't you want java script on clientside?

Comment: @acidzombie24 To store them on clientside with javascript ? how ? can you make an example ? You question is to keep the post data somewhere so we re-post them after some action. Correct ?

Comment: @Aristos: I was to lazy. I actually ended up just haveing captcha on or off by config file and had it off all this time bc it never got popular. If I were to do it in javascript i'd just not use form submitt and use ajax than add in the captcha when server request for it. Like what deed02392 said

Comment: How to actually do it I dont know but i think there is a jquery serialization function where you can give it an ID/DOM and it will make a string similar to "u=1&z=2&etc=123". Than use `$.post` or `$.ajax` to send it to the server

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just write the form data out to the captcha page in hidden elements with the additional captcha fields added to the form.  Have your submit action post the whole thing back to the original.  Using ASP.NET it's probably easier to have the captcha written to the same page with the form fields hidden, but you can do cross-page postbacks as I've described above.

Answer (score 1):

[Cross Page Posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement the CAPTCHA with AJAX? Load the captcha object and form with Javascript in a div perhaps displayed lightbox style, accept the user input and post it to your server for validation, hence continue with the users post request or keep them there until they get it right (or cancel).

**A more specific situation example:**

Give the form submittal button an onClientClick value of some Javascript function. This function decides if this particular form needs a CAPTCHA. If it does it loads an interface for taking the CAPTCHA (which you'd need to do with some server-side code) and inserts the CAPTCHA's input element to the form that the user clicked to submit.

Once the user has entered the CAPTCHA input and clicks some button whose click event is bound to return to your first JS function, the Javascript intercepts this action and posts the full form, all the data from the original form and the CAPTCHA for validation. Your server script can now process all this at once!

This is the best solution I can think of that works similar to how you've asked, but I can't imagine why you want to perform the CAPTCHA on a different page.

Comment: First of all there are many ways to implement the Captcha. In this question for many reason I ask for this way - not other way. Why is that ? Ok, think that a user click on a submit button, and a page have many submit ways, how to capture all that in a general way ? I like to see if the user have make many submit on the page_load and there decide if I throw him to a captach page. And to make this as general as possible to capture all pages and all post back, must be some where on code behind on the page. Also this must work without javascript as most attacks calls not use javascript.

Comment: Why not capture form submits with a postback rather than a full page submit? Then you can have your own routines per form submittal as well as make the decision to render a captcha object on the page.

Comment: First thank you for your interesting. I am not sure that I understand your idea on this, can you post some code ?

Comment: I have refined my explanation please check the edit. There would be a lot of code involved so I think once you understand the method it would be best to post individual questions on how to get that to work if you cannot do it.

Comment: wow a bounty on my old question. I cant remember what i end up doing but I -think- my issue was I wanted to validate the data and if something was suspicious to throw a captcha. But I wanted an easy way to store the data on client side thus 'carry' the post data. I think this was for spam attacks. I probably just generate a form with the captcha in it but i was lazy and didnt want to generate a bunch of hidden inputs and didnt want to put it as a get request (ie `form?<post data here>`). It was also for a number of pages. Theres also the file upload issue but nevermind that. CC @Aristos

Comment: There are usually more efficient and easier ways to determine if a client is genuine. The best example I can think of is to send the client a challenge in Javascript which it must process and post back to prove it's a genuine session. From then on you can reasonably safely assume what that client posts comes from a human.

Comment: @acidzombie24 dont you like the bounty on your old request ? :) I have some solutions, just looking to see if there are any better

Comment: @deed02392 cool but its atistos bounty so figure out what he wants ;). I just posted for clarification on my original question to provide potential insight.

Comment: IMHO my solution is better but I don't care about a bounty, I'm here to make software development discussions not build up some arbitrary score :)

Comment: @deed02392 Your solution is not working with out javascript - I will tell you one more time. The most attacks are from programs with out javascript. This programs I try to eliminate. So this is the reason that I look for non javascript solution. And one more, there are many buttons in a page - how a javascript function decide if he need captcha page ? a bad user opens many page and make many post back at the same time... from different page.

Comment: @deed02392 I give you the 100 only for not throw them away, to you that you have low points and a nice answer :) even if I do not find what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`Server.Transfer` with `MultiViews, Panels like control` is fine with you? In this way, no need to bother about the `Data Maintenance` and `Postbacks`. You can do the validations in javascript.

You can keep both functionality in the same page to avoid moving data from one page to another page/Bring the data back to original page. You can utilize `Session` for this intermediate operation. Set it back to associated controls across Postback. You can create a `class`, `Instantiate` it and `Initialize the control values` in this class object. Save class object in `Session`. On Postback, You can reassign the values to the `associated controls`. This will definitely keep the things simple and without much complexity.

Doubts ?

Comment: if you make Server.Transfer after the post back you need to go again back to the second page, and then again round trip to the first one - how you can do that ? Can you make a practical working code  ?

Comment: Sorry, did not mention the Point of View properly. Please check my appended suggestion.

Comment: I make a sample my self, after the first Server.Transfer, you need to make a postback, then you have a second Server.Transfer, and then you need again to make a new postback, after the Server.Transfer. So Server.Transfer can not hold by him self all the rounds.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my post. can you see my second paragraph again ?

Comment: Yes I see it, Session is not working for users with out cookie enable, and this is the most of attackers. Also session have time outs, this is what in some case try to resolve, the timeout of a login user.